# Metric Tensors in Geodesic Normal Coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider the unit sphere and its north pole $(0, 0, 1)$. My question is how to write the metric tensor $g_{ij}$ in geodesic normal coordinates. I know that metric tensors are defined as inner product $\langle \partial_i, \partial_j\rangle$. However, how do I find $\partial_i$ and $\partial_j$ in normal coordinates, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential map is given by

$$ \exp_p : T_pS \to S,\ \ v \mapsto \gamma_v(1),$$

where $\gamma_v$ is a geodesic with $\gamma(0)= p = (0,0,1)$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. Now we identify $T_pS$ with the $(x, y)$-plane. We know that all geodesics are great circles, so for any $v = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, then $\gamma_v$ will be a geodesic in the great circle $S \cap L_v$, where $L_v$ is the plane spanned by $v$ and $(0,0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^3$. So you need to find the point $q$ in $S\cap L_v$ such that the $d(p, q) = r = |v|$. Then $q = \gamma_v(1) = \exp_p (v)$.

So the map can be written down explicitly:

$$\exp_p(r, \theta) = (\sin r\cos\theta,  \sin r \sin\theta , \cos r)$$

and now everything is standard:

$$\partial_r  =(\cos r\cos \theta, \cos r \sin\theta, -\sin r), $$

$$\partial_\theta = (-\sin r\sin \theta, \sin r\cos\theta, 0),$$

$$g_{rr} = 1,\ g_{r\theta} = 0, \ g_{\theta\theta} = \sin ^2 r.$$

Comment: For a given tangent vector $v$ on the tangent plane, I know its length is $r$. Hence the corresponding point $q$ on $S$ is simply the point which makes an angle of $r$ with the positive $z$ axis and making an angle of $\theta$ with the positive $x$ axis since this way $d(p, q)=2\pi\times 1 \times r/(2\pi)=r$.

Comment: @20824: Perfect!

Comment: @20824: I just edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: Can I parametrise the surface using $(r, \theta)$ by $(\sin r\cos\theta, \sin r\sin \theta, \cos r)$, please? Thanks, I was working in that direction.

Comment: @20824 Yes, that's exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: But as it turned out, this is simply the standard somehow parameterisation of sphere. Right? I cannot see where the normal coordinates plays a role.

Comment: @20824: do you understand why $\exp_p(r, \theta) = (\sin r\cos\theta,  \sin r \sin\theta , \cos r)$?

Comment: It might be the standard parametrization, but more importantly it is the normal coordinate at $p$.

Comment: @20824: you can consider $g_{ij}$ is defined in a local coordinate, but not the whole manifold.

Comment: Tell me, are we not talking about standard geodesic polar coordinates with the orthogonal circles  of constant geodesic curvature?

Comment: @Narasimham : Yes, we are talking about geodesic polar coordinates.